# Tomcat 7 CLOSE_WAIT

Tags: tomcat, apache-traffic-server

Our application has a set of Apache Traffic Servers which send the request to a load balancer which send the request to a tomcat server version 7.

Tomcat server seems to be responding but after some time there are a number of CLOSE_WAIT sockets from Tomcat to Apache Traffic Server.

On restarting Tomcat 7 these sockets are closed.

At the same time, there are no sockets in CLOSE_WAIT on Traffic Server.

Request your inputs

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand:

> CLOSE-WAIT: The local end-point has received a connection termination
>   request and acknowledged it e.g. a passive close has been performed
>   and the local end-point needs to perform an active close to leave this
>   state.
>
> TIME-WAIT: The local end-point waits for twice the maximum segment
>   lifetime (MSL) to pass before going to CLOSED to be sure that the
>   remote end-point received the acknowledgement.

Your Tomcat has received a connection termination... and your tomcat needs to perform an active close to leave this state.
In your Apache Traffic Server connections maybe will be in TIME_WAIT for a short configured timeout until it close.
If you have connection leaks you could try to update Tomcat to a last version to avoid bugs and make a review of your application to ensure release your resources.

If the number of connections in this state isn't big, I would't give too much importance.

A link to understand some TCP states:

http://benohead.com/tcp-about-fin_wait_2-time_wait-and-close_wait/

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem on standalone Tomcat. Here is what I did to solve it:

1. Kill the tomcat process
2. Restart tomcat
3. On Windows: `netstat -ano | find "your_tomcat_port"` and `taskkill /pid the_pid /F`
4. On Linux: `lsof -i:your_tomcat_port` and `kill -9 the_pid`
5. Restart Tomcat

You can create .bat or .sh script.

Comment: restarting in production is not preferable.

Comment: Restart ? A joke !!! :P